# How do I create a WIFI Accesspoint bridge to my Ethernet

Tags: networking, dhcp, network-bridge

## Question: How do I make a [Bridged] [Access Point]

(and not a Shared "Hot Spot" Access Point)

> Additional User Requested Info as follows:
>    - To be performed on Ubuntu
>    - Of version 14.04.3 or later
>    - 
>   not Lubuntu, Kubuntu, Xubuntu, etc...

Graphical UI Method preferable (as to be able to teach to the non-savy in the future)

I need to do this because the router (that im wired to)

- is too far away,
- i need bandwidth for internet and
- Also for sending files to my tablets,phones,laptops
  etc.

So noted in case someone suggests "Hotspot" I reinforce: I do not need a hosted local DHCP server AP, I need a AP Bridged to a router DHCP.

Comment: A WiFi hotspot is a general placeholder for a WiFi access. So, do you have a computer with Ethernet and WiFi? It should be easy to bridge the router connected Ethernet to the WiFi thus creating a WiFi AP in the same network. What do you call this doesn't really matter. What matters for a useful answer is knowing your Ubuntu release. Please [edit].

Comment: ... what you call it does matter.
a.) A hosted AP is when the computer assigns addresses.
b.) A Bridged AP is when the main router assigns addresses, keeping the same subnet access to other computers.

Comment: Yes, and b) is exactly what you can easily enable in the GUI network settings of most Ubuntu flavors by bridging the connections. But there are differences between releases and that's why I suggested [edit]ing your question accordingly.

Comment: ... Ok... Where?

Comment: "Where" (GUI) depends on the Ubuntu release and Desktop Environment/flavor. Again, please [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Or this: https://webby.land/2018/04/27/bridging-under-ubuntu-18-04/